# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. C# Error

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

I am writing an imaging app in WPF C#. It reads the image file pixel by pixel using unsafe code.

The problem I am getting is it throws the error `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.` when writing the pixel value. It works fine for some images and for others it shows the error. Following is the code:

```
unsafe
            {
                byte* pbuff = (byte*)buff.ToPointer();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i=i+stride)
                  {
                        pbuff[i] = (byte)cr[j].NewColor.Blue;
                        pbuff[i + 1] = (byte)cr[j].NewColor.Green; // here it shows error
                        pbuff[i + 2] = (byte)cr[j].NewColor.Red;
                   }
            }
```

**EDIT**

Reading of the pixels works fine.

```
                B = (double)pbuff[i];
                G = (double)pbuff[i + 1];
                R = (double)pbuff[i + 2];
```

It does not shows any error while reading but for the same index (that was read) it shows error when attempted to write.

Comment: Your code is missing the essential parts. And I suspect the way you use stride is wrong too.

Comment: Why are you reading doubles and writing bytes?  Also, have you pinned the buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this means that you are trying to write to the memory outside the memory allocated for the object referenced by pbuff.

So this is basically the same as array index out of bounds in safe code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But reading of the pixel is working fine!

Comment: @Vinod = Knobloch's answer was specfic to writting to memory outside of the memory allocated.  What you need to do is "get" the memory store it locally and then place it back into memory.  One way of doing this is to use a struct.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WPF, you should not use unsafe code, but instead play nice with WPF. This is what the [WriteableBitmap Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28VS.85%29.aspx) is for I think.